# What are the consequences of leaving the fridge door cracked open overnight?

Tags: temperature, refrigerator, raw-meat, food-safety

My girlfriend accidentally didn't close the fridge properly and left it open 2 inches all night (more than 8 hours). I had a lot of raw chicken breast and raw salmon in there. Is it still edible? When I touched the meat, it was slightly colder than room temperature (21 C).

The back part of the meat was still a bit cold though because it was closer to the back of the fridge.

Is it edible?

Comment: When did you last clean the cooling coils on your fridge? I've had mine open a crack all night and things got nowhere near that warm. Dirty coils make a fridge inefficient and subject to thermal shutdowns.

Comment: Also beware that if the fridge has a freezer compartment, that may have warmed up, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the food had reached a temperature of 21 C for an unknown amount of time, you should definitely discard it.

See:
[How do I know if food left at room temperature is still safe to eat?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat)

---

As a more general rule, there really is no way to provide a definitive answer; it depends on your specific refrigerator, the cooling power it has, how much air was able to move through the gap, and how much mass was inside the refrigerator to provide a thermal buffer

If you had a refrigerator thermometer and looked at what temperature the interior rose to, if it was below 40 F you are good.

If you don't have a thermometer, you don't know exactly what happened inside.

You must assess how much tolerance for risk you have.

Comment: Given that the meat was 21C (70F) or so, there's pretty much no way it's safe.

Comment: @Jefromi Ah, I missed that; that is what I get for late night answering!